# Migrating very large elasticsearch indices

Tags: elasticsearch

We ran out of space due to a very large indices (5TB primary | 5TB replica). This indices has 5 shards (each shard is 1TB). We are planning to migrate this indices to bigger AWS instance type. Please let me know what are the settings that can be modified for the migration to go fast and smooth?

Note: We are using default elasticsearch settings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd like to point out that having a 1TB shard is way off from the recommended 30gb limit. I'd also assume that due to this your cluster probably isn't as optimised as expected in even extreme scenarios.

Secondly, the recommended settings would depend on the track you're using to migrate this index?

I'd personally let snapshot/restore to take care of the process as it would use the least bandwidth and hence refusing the transfer time. Once done, since snapshot is already in an AWS region, it would be faster to restore.

Again, I'm assuming a lot here so alot depends on your limitations and preferred method.

All the best.

Comment: How to increase the speed of shard migration using move command? If we increase 'indices : store:  throttle : max_bytes_per_sec' from 20mb default to higher value help?

Comment: max_bytes_per_sec can be pushed upto say 200mb and turning off any throttling would definitely help.

Comment: How about indices.recovery.concurrent_streams? Is this settings is to increase no. of threads that will be open for a shard during recovery?